# How to access RecursiveArrayIterator by index?

Tags: php, json

How to access `RecursiveArrayIterator` by index without a loop? I have the following code

```
$json = file_get_contents("careers.json");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

<select class="form-control position" name="position" required>
<?php $option = 0;
foreach($jsonIterator as $key => $val){ 
if(is_array($val)){ $option++; ?>
<option value="<?= $option; ?>"><?= $key; ?></option>  
<?php }}?> 
</select>
```

I just want to send the key by email, if I supply the key to the option instead of the value, ChosenJS wouldn't work properly

I could do another loop to send the key which is what I'm currently temporarily doing but its just wrong, `Peehaa` suggested on chat to store `json_decode` and access that.

There are many possible solutions but I'm interested in accessing it this way for educational purposes

```
$index = $_POST['position'];
$key= $jsonIterator[$index];
```

Json sample, it's a file which lots of paragraphs, this is an example structure:

```
{
    "this is the key i want to get": {
        "short":"this is a title ",     
        "Location":"somewhere", 
        "Close":""
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a reduced sample JSON you're trying to access items from, so we have a better idea of how complex its structure is.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't make sense. You're iterating `$jsonIterator` two lines before you create it.

Comment: @Smuuf please read my edit